# Asterisk and Fortran statement

Tags: fortran, double, comments, notepad++, fortran77

I have a Fortran 77 code that shows a comment in the first column and written `double precision` in the same line. now my text editor (Notepad++) is showing that as a statement. I am confused if it is a statement or a comment.

[image]

```
*   double precision Ct,Jt,PDt,AeA0t,Zt,Cq,Jq,PDq,AeA0q,Zq,
*   &Kt,Kq,Eta,J,PD,AeA0
```

Comment: You must show more complete piece of code. Especially we must be sure which column is that one containing the `*` and which column contains the `&`.

Comment: I would say Notepad++ is not understanding the Fortran 77 syntax. It doesn't think the line is a comment even though it is.

Answer (score 3):

First, the text editor syntax highlighting is not something you can trust 100%. It is just there to help you, but it can be wrong and it can differ from an editor to an editor.

Second, if that code compiles, it must be a comment. Otherwise the ampersand `&` would cause an error. The ampersand can be used in the sixth column to continue the previous line, but it has to be the first character of the line.

Answer (score 1):

It's a comment. If there's anything other than a whitespace in the first column of a line in a fixed-form fortran (That is Fortran up to F77), it's a comment.

These variables are not declared, but if the code doesn't have an `implicit none`, they would be implicitly declared, some as `REAL`, some as `INTEGER`.

Comment: Comments are indicated by `C` or `*` in the first column, not arbitrary non-whitespace.  Label numbers may appear in that column.

Comment: You're right, a digit would not be a comment. But I have been using `!` as comment indicators, so I assume that would be okay...

Comment: Yes, from F90 `!` as the first non-blank character of a line (except in column 6) indicates a comment line.  That's a property of `!` rather than of the first column, though.  Notably, several compilers accept `D` in the first column as a "conditional comment line".